# iPod will not forget!

Tags: apple-id, ipod-touch

My iPod Touch was originally used with an Apple account and email that have become obsolete. I no longer have access to the email account and cannot supply the old password or ask for a password change to be sent by email as I no longer have that account.

I have been to the Store setting, tapped the Apple ID and changed it to my new, active email and Apple account. However, when I try to go to the Store to download something, for example, I am still asked for the password to the old account!

Please tell me how to solve this earth shattering, life or death, bowel moving, insanity inducing problem!

Comment: Did you try at to get access to your old account on iforgot.apple.com?

Comment: Also, when you say you *go to the 'Store' to download something*, do you mean you're trying to download something totally new, or that you're trying to update any existing app? Basically, anything downloaded previously with another Apple ID is *linked* to that Apple ID. In other words, you would need to download the apps again from scratch using your new Apple ID.

Comment: The iPod itself also belongs to the old ID. Apple never forgets an ID, so if you want access, you need to change its associated email address; you can't abandon it as it won't let you.

Comment: It’s unclear which problem of 2 that you are having (or maybe it’s both).  iCloud requires a password to logout if find my iPhone is turned on, that’s part of theft protection.  Second, as @Monomeeth points out, an app downloaded under one appleid will always require that appleid to update.  The cleanest path to changing appleid on a device is to turn off find my device, log out of iCloud then Erase all content and settings, then reset up the device.  Any deviation from that will result in requests for the old appleid’s password.

Comment: Thanks Tyson. I am not an 'apple guy' so my description of what the problem is may not be as clear as it might. I think that you might be on to something with turning off the 'find my device' thing. I have completely reset the ipod and logged back onto iTunes using a new apple id which seems to work but, when the ipod is turned on I get the request for the pasword to an old id the memory of which has faded into the mists of time! I have no access to the email used as the apple id and no memory of what the password might have been 6 or seven year ago! Where is find that 'find my device' option?